# ActionScript 3 to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Is there any way to convert ActioScript3 code to JavaScript?

Noting both languages I noticed that they have many similarities.

I'm used to write OOP code in ActionScript 3 and would be very useful to be able to port it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what do you want to convert. If it's a visual application with animation and transitions - you won't be able to do anything. Javascript doesn't have interfaces, nor it has such types as Vector or other strongly typed things.

However, there is [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) which enables you to write code in one language and automatically convert it both to AS3 and JavaScript (and others).

There's also a canvas lib [EaseJS](http://www.createjs.com) which has flash-like API

Comment: Hi think EaseJS is what I need. It's OOP styled, and have some features as filters, sprites, tweening. http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/apitest